# clear dynamic input value text (can't use placeholder)

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

```
$("input").on("click", function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "Please enter a value greater than or equal to 3.")
        $(this).val("")
});
```

Comment: Is this for real? That is the most bizarre question I ever saw on SO

Comment: Are you aware of the `placeholder` attribute? `<input placeholder="please enter a value...">`

Comment: I can't use placeholder because the text within changes dynamically.

Comment: But doesn't clearing the text always on focus make the input rather useless and annoying.

Comment: "So I was looking for a way to check the length...". I agree with the sentiment above that `placeholder` is probably better, but look at my answer for an example of checking the input value's length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$("input").on("click", function() {
    if ($(this).val().length > 0)
        $(this).val("");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input value="some text" />
```

Answer (score 3):

Just remove all your `if ($(this).val() == "...")` checks.

There's really no harm in setting an already-empty input to an empty string, but if you really want to check, you can do the following:

```
$("input").on("click", function() {
    if ($(this).val().length) {
        $(this).val("");
    }
});
```

Comment: There's no point in the length check. If length > 0, clear the value. If length == 0 there's no content anyway, so you can just set `val('')` regardless.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan That's more-or-less what I explained. The extra step made more sense in light of the question as it was worded 19 edits ago...